# Exception not handled in caller module with async and anonymous methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, task, async-await

i'm testing my class librabry that makes async post to a webserver.
Since the data to send require different manipolation, i insert the method to process and send them inside a blockingcollection. A task that run forever extract each method from the collection and execute it.
The problem is that if the post fails, the error doesn't bubble to the wpf caller module.

**Here's the library module**

```
private Task queueInvio;
private BlockingCollection<Action> codaInvio = null;

public MotoreClient()
    {
        codaInvio = new BlockingCollection<Action>();

        queueInvio = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Action azione = null;
                if (codaInvio.TryTake(out azione))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        azione();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        , CancellationToken.None
        , TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
        , TaskScheduler.Default);
    }
```

**This is the method called by the wpf test program**

```
        public void InviaAggiornamento(TipoAggiornamento tipoAggiornamento)
    {
        string nomePaginaApi = String.Empty;
        HttpContent contenuto = null;

        switch (tipoAggiornamento)
        {
            // blah blah code
        }

        // exception capture here, but not rethrown to the wpf module
        codaInvio.Add(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                await InviaAggiornamento(nomePaginaApi, contenuto);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }

        });
    }
```

**This is the method that make the async post**

```
private async Task InviaAggiornamento(string nomePaginaApi, HttpContent contenuto)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        string riposta = String.Empty;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(indirizzoServer))
        {
            try
            {
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(IndirizzoServer);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", USERNAME, PASSWORD))));

                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("api/liveTimingApi/" + nomePaginaApi, contenuto);

                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
                    throw new Exception("Richiesta PostAsync fallita.");

                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string rispostaErrore = string.Empty;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.ReasonPhrase))
                        rispostaErrore += " ReasonPhrase: " + response.ReasonPhrase;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result))
                        rispostaErrore += " Result: " + response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    throw new ServerException(rispostaErrore.Trim());
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException hre)
            {
                throw new Exception("HttpRequestException: " + hre.Message);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                throw new Exception("Richiesta cancellata (TaskCanceledException).");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Exception: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (httpClient != null)
                {
                    httpClient.Dispose();
                    httpClient = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**This is wpf module that simulate the send of the data**

```
        private void btnSendTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        motoreClient.IndirizzoServer = "http://localhost:721";
        motoreClient.AggiungiRigaProgrammaOrario(1, 1, "GaraDescrizione", DateTime.Now, "XXX", "SessioneDescrizione", "1:00:00", true);

        try
        {
            motoreClient.InviaAggiornamento(TipoAggiornamento.ProgrammaOrario);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Since the IndirizzoServer (server address) is fake i have an HttpRequest exception.
I capture it inside the codaInvio.Add try/catch block, but I'm not able to rethrow it to the caller wpf module.
Visual studio says that the exception is not handled by the caller code.
Why? I'm using try/catch all the relevant piece of code.

If i'm not clear please let me know.

Marco

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could refactor these snippets into a short but complete program we could easily copy, paste, compile and run...

Comment: Here you. A zip with the solution..just hit the button. I'm waiting a messagebox to appear, instead it block on throw inside codaInvio.Add() http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1406633237

Comment: No, I didn't ask for a zip file. Is this actually WPF specific? Have you tried it in a console app? You could probably reproduce this in a program which is short enough to just paste straight in...

Answer (score 2):

Your core problem is here:

```
BlockingCollection<Action>
```

`Action` is a `void`-returning delegate type, so when you pass an `async` lambda to `Add`, it is creating an `async void` method. There are several reasons to avoid `async void`; one is that it's *not possible* to catch exceptions from them using `try`/`catch`.

You *could* change the delegate type to be compatible with `async Task`, i.e., `BlockingCollection<Func<Task>>`, assuming that all the delegates passed to `Add` are `async`. This would require your "run forever" task to `await` the result, making its delegate also `async`. And then you'd need to change from `Task.Factory.StartNew` to `Task.Run` because [`StartNew` doesn't understand `async` delegates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).

But really, I'd recommend a much simpler solution: use an `ActionBlock` from TPL Dataflow (available via NuGet).